# how to find value in nested array and then change the value from boolean to string?

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, nested

How change the value in "active" (true to "Yes" /false to "No").

[
{
"id":81,
"time":"2022-01-01 19:30:00",
"subList":[
{
"active":false,
"success":null
}
]
},
{
"id":89,
"time":"2022-01-01 21:00:15",
"subList":[
{
"active":true,
"success":1
}
]
}
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Array.map

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or any other looping to loop through the elements of an array.

You can use `?` and `:` [Conditional ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
to shorten a simple if else block.

```js
const list = [ { "id":81, "time":"2022-01-01 19:30:00", "subList":[ { "active":false, "success":null } ] }, { "id":89, "time":"2022-01-01 21:00:15", "subList":[ { "active":true, "success":1 } ] } ];

const newList = list.map(item => {
    item.subList.map(subItem => {
        subItem.active = subItem.active ? "Yes" : "No"
        return subItem;
    })
    return item;
})

console.log(newList)
```